# Android Animation on focused button (state_focused)

Tags: android, animation, button, imageview

For example i have few buttons, and one ImageView.
I using keyboard to control the Android, 
For focused or pressed button i use different state image.

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/newbtfocus" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressednewbt" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

Now i need to change the imageview on focused button. 
For example:

- Then focused button 1 the imageview show Fredy Mercury.
- Then focused    button 2 the imageview show Jackson.
- Then focused button 3 the    imageview show AC DC

and other.

Thank's a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily you can do same of this example below:

```
btn2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    // the button has focused do what you want "like below"
                    myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.jackson);
                }
            }
        });
```